# how to use IN query in cakephp to find multiple values

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using `LIKE` query but when `specialist_id`'s order change it say no records found,
if `specialist_id` array have [1,2,3] in it then all the users with three specialties should be in results regardless of sequence, sequence array may have [3,2,1] or [2,1,3] but the users with these three specialties should be in results, here is my code with `LIKE` query:

```
$field = $this->User->find(
    'all', array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'User.specialist_id LIKE' =>'%'.$value.'%',
            'User.role'=>'careproviderRole',
            'User.gender'=>$this->request->data['gender'])
    )
);

foreach ($field as $key => $value)
{
    $field[$key]['Specialist'] = $user;
}
```

I have also tried with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
$field = $this->User->find(
    'all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.role' => 'careproviderRole',
            'FIND_IN_SET(\''.$this->request->data['specialist_id'].'\', User.specialist_id)')
    )
);
```

Comment: please clarify: is users.specialist_id a string ora an integer? It seems you are storing an array in your field. If so it is a bad database design. You should create a table (i.e. users_speciaists) to store the specialists associated to every user so that you can use `matching()` in your query

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LIKE` with mask `'%some%'`, it find all results with substring 'some'.

If you need to get some specific set of ids from table (1, 2 or 3), then use sql operator `IN`.

Example:

```
SELECT `specialist_id` FROM `User` WHERE `specialist_id` IN (1,2,3);
```

In your code it will be:

```
$field = $this->User->find(
'all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'User.specialist_id' => $arrayOfSpecialistIds,
        'User.role'=>'careproviderRole',
        'User.gender'=>$this->request->data['gender'])
)
```

Comment: yes, but this IN simple sql query how to use it in cakephp?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: actually the single record field in table has multiple values like specialist_id column has 1,2,3 ids in it,means the userabc has these 3 specialties .
now,when multiple specialties are selected suppose [3,2,1], then all the users with these three types of specialties must be in result,the solution your provided still didn't work